# How to send raw 802.11 packet without AP and use linux own socket interface?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, wifi

Sorry for my bad english.

I want to build a prototype for testing [TI-SmartConfig how it works](https://depletionregion.blogspot.com/2013/10/cc3000-smart-config-transmitting-ssid.html?showComment=1477367696172#c728965950942506877) on 2 RaspberryPi like linux based system. They're called OPi but the wifi chip supports monitor mode.

Then I have to transmit raw 802.11 packets from OPi A to OPi B. If I connect OPi-A to an AP, then use sendto() to generate packets, then the packets can be monitored by OPi-B. But is OPi-A is not connected to AP, I've tried many times and searched though this site and finally can not reach a solution.

My questions are,

1, In this case: OPi-A(managed mode, connect to AP)-----AP-----OPi-B(monitor mode, not connected to AP), is it possible that OPi-B transmit packets back to OPi-A? I guess no...

2, In this case: OPi-A(monitor mode, not connected to AP) - OPi-B(monitor mode, not connected to AP), is it possible to transmit/fake raw 802.11 packets(beacon\qos\data\probe all acceptable) from A to B? Packet contents are not concerned.

3, Is it possible to do what question 2 said by linux socket interface, not by third party mods/drivers?

Any suggestions and code samples are appreciated! Believe me, I really searched through here ...